# Are there different priority in otp gen_server's info, call, cast message queue?

Tags: erlang, message-queue, gen-server

When writing codes, I ask myself which type of message should use `call`, which type of message should use `info`?

Below this question, there is another long-time doubt whether there is priority difference between `info, cast, call` message? whether these 3 type of messages share the same queue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Priority of messages is the same. Quick look into gen_server.erl and you will discover simple loop receiving all data.

```
loop(Parent, Name, State, Mod, hibernate, Debug) ->
    proc_lib:hibernate(?MODULE,wake_hib,[Parent, Name, State, Mod, Debug]);
loop(Parent, Name, State, Mod, Time, Debug) ->
    Msg = receive
          Input ->
            Input
      after Time ->
          timeout
      end,
    decode_msg(Msg, Parent, Name, State, Mod, Time, Debug, false).
```

About [handle_info](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#Module:handle_info-2):

> This function is called by a gen_server when a timeout occurs or when it receives any other message than a synchronous or asynchronous request (or a system message).

For example timeout, tcp, udp, EXIT, sytem info and many others that dont fit into handle_call or handle_cast.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean when to use `call` and when to use `cast`? `info` is used for timeouts or when other kinds of message than `call` and `cast` are received by the server.

To decide whether to use `call` or `cast` I think you should ask the question "Does the sender want to wait for an answer for this kind of message?". If yes use `call` which is synchronous, if no use `cast` which is asynchronous.

But it has been a while since I used Erlang.